# Is there a self-timer mode on the GoPro Hero 3+?

Tags: gopro, time, self-timer

I might have missed the option in the plethora of settings, but it seems that there's no self-timer mode on the GoPro 3+. If there isn't, how do you take a "selfie" group shot with monopod?

Comment: "selfie" group shot with *monopod* sound like quite a feat. but since you later talk about scuba diving I guess you'll be holding it at the other end of the pod.

Comment: @MichaelNielsen That is correct. The GoPro3+ loses quite a bit of its wide angle range under water so a longer monopod is needed for a good underwater group selfie.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, the GoPro Hero 3+ does not have a self-timer mode.

But there are several ways of taking 'selfie' photos:

- You could set the Hero to timelapse mode, ie taking a photo every
  0.5, 1 or 2 seconds. Press the shutter, and it will start taking a series of photos. So you can then get in position for the selfie, and it will get a number of photos of you.
- You can do a similar thing in video mode. ie just record a video clip. Then you can get a still photo by taking a snapshot from the video (VLC media player is useful for this). This image won't be as high quality as the photo mode, videos are a bit lower resolution. But probably still good enough for sharing online.
- You could use the camera in standard single photo or burst mode, using a remote control to press the shutter. Either the GoPro Wifi Remote, or the GoPro app on a phone or tablet. Though this means you need to have a suitable remote control, and be holding it while you take the selfie.

Comment: This is sad. A self timer is pretty useful. But yeah, there's the remote. However, the remote isn't very useful when scuba diving.

Comment: +1 for the scuba. still looking for a dive pole with a dive casing for the remote.

Answer (score 1):

Yes there is:

> Changing Modes: Once camera is on, **quickly pressing the POWER/MODE button** will
>   change modes from video mode to **self-timer**, to photo mode, etc.

[Source](http://de.gopro.com/files/English-HD-HERO-Instructions-100903.pdf)

Comment: That source is the manual for the original HD Hero. The Hero 3+ is a much newer model, and is quite different. It seems the Hero 3+ does not have a self-timer mode.

Comment: Yeah, I saw this, too. It is for an older model.